# Implementing user and request authentication

Tags: php, web-services, security, https

Please pardon my ignorance for I have almost no web development experience.

I've implemented a simple mechanism whereby I hash the user password (sent as post/get parameter) and store it in a database. After a user logs in successfully, I return the user id (PK in the database) back to client. Subsequent requests must have the user ID which is used as a primitive mechanism to validate the requests.

I've read about several mechanisms starting from simple http authentication, using a salted hash (which I'm using), implementing access tokens to the seemingly complicated `OAuth` authentication. Ah! and perhaps finally about `https`.

Leaving aside the last two, which I'm still to comprehend enough, I seem to have a very basic question to which I haven't been able to find an answer.

I'm sorry this is not a direct programming question, but the reason I ask is I cannot find an answer on google or rather am not using the correct search keywords.

Question is, given all the mechanisms of access tokens and api keys etc, even if I were to implement this mechanism but do not use https, is there any point in implementing them at all? I mean just as anyone could sniff in on my clear text password or user id, he would also be able to snoop in on the token/key and use that subsequently with malicious intent thereby rendering the whole mechanism useless. Does that mean https is the only truly secure option?

I must be missing something here, but pointers would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that mean https is the only truly secure option

No, there is no single "secure" option, rather a series of mitigations you implement to reduce risk at various points of your application. HTTPS does 3 distinct things:

1. It provides assurance of the identity of the website (site verification).
2. It provides assurance that the content has not been manipulated in
   transit (data integrity).
3. It provides assurance that eavesdropping has not occurred in transit
   (data confidentiality).

If you don't use HTTPS, all the other security practices you talk of can easily be made worthless if an attacker is watching or manipulating plain text packets. Take a look at my post on [Insufficient Transport Layer Protection](http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/11/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-9.html) to see what this means in practice.

Comment: That post is awesome read. I'm a newbie in the area of security, so the later parts went over the top. Is there a source you would recommend to get all basic first. I mean there are tons on sites that deal with the subject but one doesn't know where to start.

Comment: Thanks :) If you're interested in security, start reading part 1 in my series and go from there. If it's general technology, ask lots of questions here, read lots of books, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes without HTTPS some random hacker could potentially sniff packets coming too and fro from your system and steal information about logins.