# How to ONLY be able to send a request from an app

Tags: java, php, android, httpwebrequest

I think this is a little hard to explain. Basically, I have an android app which connects to a web app. I want requests that I make from the web app, to not be made anywhere else. I am using PHP, by the way. So if for say, I make a request from an android app called "send_data.php?foo=bar", I want that request to not work, unless its indeed sent from the android app alone. So I cant just go to my browser and type "send_data.php?foo=bar" and it will work.

I have thought of one way, and that is to have a secret value in my request like "pw=12345", and then in the PHP script, have `if($pw = "12345")`, but then I figured someone could packet sniff their phone and easily get that secret value. Is there any way possible I can accomplish this?

Comment: use ssl (https) to send data from the android app to the web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qasim,

One way you could do it is to use a post instead of a get variable and then access the link as an SSL link.  Doing so would make sure that the posted information is encrypted.  If you can't do that you could do like I did.  I encrypted the data that I am sending to the phone on the server. It stays encrypted on the phone and is only decrypted when it is used in the app.  This way it doesn't matter if someone sniffs my connection and gets the data.  It's all but useless.  Hope this helps.

Comment: But how would I encrypt it? What method would I use that would let me encrypt the data, but is reversible as well (decryptable)?

Comment: You could any number of encryption methods as long as the key is stored on the server and the phone and not transmitted it is fairly well protected from sniffing.  I used DES with mine (Not one of the most secure but enough for me).  The PHP page encrypts the data before sending it via HTTPS in JSON format.  The phone accepts the data and stores it encrypted in a database.  Later when the app needs to use the data, it decrypts it. Like NMR said the key can be found in your source with enough work. The trick is to make it as secure as possible using things like Proguard to obfuscate your code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be done in a cryptographically secure way. The phone app itself is public data so any key stored inside the app is ultimately sniffable.

That said you can go to reasonable lengths to obfuscate the key, store it in an encrypted format, hide where it is, etc. This might be enough deterrence for your purposes. But it's important to know that it's all just shell game, keys in apps are insecure and a motivated attacker will eventually extract it.

Another approach you might consider is to have the user authenticate, then you can know who's connecting and you can base your server response on that. User authentication is cryptographically strong.

Answer (score 0):

There's no perfect answer.  I would make the site send a key that's used to encrypt the data but even then that could be defeated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are wondering about request authentication and are also concerned about someone sniffing the data while in transit. Using https is the only way to mitigate all risks. See the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792947/implementing-user-and-request-authentication/8798060#8798060). The blog link provided in the answer is worth the read.